# How to find duplicate values by group in SQL

Tags: sql, clickhouse

Let's say I have a simple table like this:

| company | product |
| --- | --- |
| a | 123 |
| a | 124 |
| b | 123 |
| b | 125 |
| c | 126 |
| c | 127 |

The product number *123* is duplicated between company a and company b. I want to summarize this duplication in a table that looks like this:

| company | total_products | total_unique_products |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2 | 1 |
| b | 2 | 1 |
| c | 2 | 2 |

Is there a way to create this in SQL (specifically Clickhouse but a generic example will help)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
create table Slava_Ukraini(company String, product UInt64)
Engine=Memory as select * from values (('a',    123),
('a',   124),('b',  123),('b',  125),('c',  126),('c',  127));


select arrayJoin(g) company, count() total_products, countIf(cnt=1) total_unique_products
from  (
        select groupArray(company) g, length(arrayDistinct(g)) cnt, product
        from Slava_Ukraini
        group by product
      )
group by company
order by company

┌─company─┬─total_products─┬─total_unique_products─┐
│ a       │              2 │                     1 │
│ b       │              2 │                     1 │
│ c       │              2 │                     2 │
└─────────┴────────────────┴───────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Slava Ukraini!
Worked great, thank you.